# Inverted Staircase in columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

http://jsfiddle.net/h0unc0xx/

(or)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGNOQW

```
    code in jsfiddle & codepen
```

```css
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
GLOBAL FIXES
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  zoom: 1;
  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
MOBILE-FIRST STYLING BEGINS HERE
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #C5C9C8;
}
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: Impact !important;
  line-height: 0.9 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 6em !important;
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}
a {
  color: #f03;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #f03;
  color: white;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
  -moz-border-radius: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
}
a.btn:hover {
  background: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header {
  background: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 3em 0em 0em 0em;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 0.25em solid #f03;
}
header p {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
blockquote {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3em;
  background: black;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
#main {
  margin: 2em;
}
section img {
  background: #B8B8B8;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}
section {
  display: inline;
}
footer#credits {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f03;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
}
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
MEDIA QUERIES FOR LARGER BREAKPOINTS BEGIN HERE
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

/*
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
 section{
 width: 31.481481481481481481481481481481%;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 2.777777777777777777777777777778%;
 
}

section:first-child{
 margin-left: 0px; 
}

}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <title>Time Travel</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <!-- Raw page content, ready for semantic structuring -->
  <header>
    <h1>Time Travel</h1>

    <p>Because sometimes you just need to travel through some time.</p>


    <blockquote>
      <p>"Time travel into the indefinite future is consistent with the laws of nature."</p>

    </blockquote>

    <div id="main" role="main" class="group row">


      <section class="col-md-4">
        <img src="imgs/wormhole.png" alt="Worm Holes">

        <h2>Using Wormholes</h2>

        <p>
          There is no observational evidence for wormholes, but on a theoretical level there are valid solutions to the equations of the theory of general relativity which contain wormholes. Because of its robust theoretical strength, a wormhole is also known as
          one of the great physics metaphors for teaching general relativity.</p>

        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </p>
      </section>
      <section class="col-md-4">
        <img src="imgs/time-dilation.png" alt="Time Dilation">
        <h2>Time Dilation</h2>
        <p>Time dilation is permitted by Albert Einstein's special and general theories of relativity. These theories state that, relative to a given observer, time passes more slowly for bodies moving quickly relative to that observer, or bodies that are
          deeper within a gravity well.
          <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </p>
      </section>

      <section class="col-md-4">
        <img src="imgs/many-worlds.png" alt="Many Worlds">
        <h2>Parallel Universes</h2>
        <p>The many-worlds interpretation is an interpretation of quantum mechanics that asserts the objective reality of the universal wavefunction, but denies the actuality of wavefunction collapse. Many-worlds implies that all possible alternative histories
          and futures are real, each representing an actual "world" (or "universe").
          <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </p>
      </section>



      <section class="col-md-4">
        <img src="imgs/wormhole.png" alt="Worm Holes">

        <h2>Using Wormholes</h2>

        <p>
          There is no observational evidence for wormholes, but on a theoretical level there are valid solutions to the equations of the theory of general relativity which contain wormholes. Because of its robust theoretical strength, a wormhole is also known as
          one of the great physics metaphors for teaching general relativity.</p>

        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </p>
      </section>
      <section class="col-md-4">
        <img src="imgs/time-dilation.png" alt="Time Dilation">
        <h2>Time Dilation</h2>
        <p>Time dilation is permitted by Albert Einstein's special and general theories of relativity. These theories state that, relative to a given observer, time passes more slowly for bodies moving quickly relative to that observer, or bodies that are
          deeper within a gravity well.
          <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </p>
      </section>

      <section class="col-md-4">
        <img src="imgs/many-worlds.png" alt="Many Worlds">
        <h2>Parallel Universes</h2>
        <p>The many-worlds interpretation is an interpretation of quantum mechanics that asserts the objective reality of the universal wavefunction, but denies the actuality of wavefunction collapse. Many-worlds implies that all possible alternative histories
          and futures are real, each representing an actual "world" (or "universe").
          <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </p>
      </section>



    </div>


    <footer id="credits">© Albert Einstein</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Please see this example. Expand browser window and result frame in jsfiddle to see the inverted staircase.

Please let me know what is wrong with my styling.

I understand that a row can only have 12 units of column size, but I have used this approach previously and it worked. Helpful when we build the columns dynamically and we do not know the exact number. I dont know why wouldn't it work now.

Even without bootstrap, when I used media queries with float:left and width: 33% I had the same effect so I dont claim it to be a bootstrap issue, something's wrong with my code. A second eye could be helpful.

Comment: JSFiddle may not always be around - please copy your code into your question :)

Comment: @Alex : Sorry, Im not able to add my long code with the indent restrictions. Its partially off.. So have added a codepen link too. Please have a look :)

Comment: @user1102532 Select all of your code and then click the "Code Sample" button in the formatting toolbar. That should indent everything one level so it displays correctly.

Comment: Thanks for doing that Max